# Where in FreePBX GUI possible to change mysql user and password for res_odbc_additional.conf

Tags: asterisk

I use CDR records to MySQL.
MySQL located on different machine.
If I change these settings directly in `res_odbc_additional.conf`

It working ok, until FreePBX will rewrite configuration again.

And I didn't found any GUI page to change it in FreePBX panel :(

Could anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the credentials in `/etc/amportal.conf` and `/etc/freepbx.conf` or `/etc/asterisk/freepbx.conf`.

p.s not forget install fail2ban, or you will be hacked.

Answer (score 0):

mysql
use asterisk;
select `value` from `freepbx_settings` where `keyword` = 'CDRDBPASS';
update `freepbx_settings` set `value` = 'newpass' where `keyword` = 'CDRDBPASS';
\q